# Selenium Stale Element Error: Problems Automating Google

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting a "StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document". My code is below.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
        browser.get('https://www.google.com/')
        for i in range(searchrow, numrows):

            wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
            inputGoogle=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "q")))
            company = sheet.cell_value(i, 1)
            inputGoogle.send_keys(company)
            inputGoogle.submit()

            wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
            wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "cite._Rm")))
            domain = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("cite._Rm")
            domain = domain.text
```

I tried this same code, except with a try/except as such:

```
try:
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "cite._Rm")))
    domain = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("cite._Rm")
except: StaleElementReferenceException
    continue
```

It did not solve my problem. In fact, it just ate up alot of cpu as it was just waiting and waiting.

Any ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: Please post the relevant html you are dealing with.

Comment: @LittlePanda It is any term I search in google. So if company=microsoft, then I would have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `time.sleep` and then `input = browser.find_element_by_id('q')`

Comment: This is not a good fix. It eats up cpu and computer resources. While it works, I know there's a better way of dealing with this.